# how to load all images in a folder to image stitch javacv

Tags: opencv, javacv

```
Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher.createDefault(false);
MatVector images = new MatVector(4);
images.put(0,cvLoadImage("1.jpg"));
images.put(1,cvLoadImage("2.jpg"));
images.put(2,cvLoadImage("3.jpg"));
images.put(3,cvLoadImage("4.jpg"));
```

this is going to stitch image correctly. Can you give me some ideas to load all images in a folder at once to matvector?

I have tried this:

```
File actual = new File("image path");
File list[] = actual.listFiles();
MatVector images = null; 
    for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){


        new MatVector(list.length);

        images.put(i,cvLoadImage(""));


    }
```

but it returns null values. Thank you.

Comment: it gives the error                    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at UWU_CST_09_0039.UniversityProject.ImageStitching.main(ImageStitching.java:42)   java 42 is:images.put(i,cvLoadImage(""));

Comment: This is really argent matter..can you please give any idea about this .thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it with this code:

```
for (int i=0; i<numOfPics; i++){
  images.put(i,cvLoadImage(imageNames[i]));
}
```

where numOfPics is a counter that I have and each time I take a picture is increased.
imageNames is a String array where I save the complete name of the picture (with folder), for example:

```
"/storage/sdcard0/Download/testpicture.JPG"
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are loading image one by one you wrote `images.put(0,cvLoadImage("1.jpg"));`

but when you put it in the "For" loop, you wrote

```
images.put(i,cvLoadImage(""));
```

The error probably occurred in the loop, because you didn't specify the extension of the image. I mean you didn't add .jpg in the loop.

try to do something like

```
images.put(i,cvLoadImage(i+".jpg"));
```

and see what happens.